# How get real time pipeline status running in TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have a monitor system showing the real-time status of the tasks.
Nowdays, we do task in TFS using pipeline, any proposal for the real time integration getting the status of the pipeline?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide some context. For instance some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and update your post accordingly

Comment: Provide more context on this

Comment: Not totally get your point. Could you explain more clearly, did you just want a time-tracker for your tasks in TFS.

Comment: I want monitor the status of pipeline, integrate the real-time status to a separate system.

Comment: @user10003005 Could you provide the sample to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is a query of TFS build/release Agent status. since there are many agent running, they want to monitor agent is halt, query the status of the agent. just like visiting the page of http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_AgentPool?poolId=2&_a=agents

and I did check the TFS2018 rest API 4.1 version, it seems there is no API to query the build agent status and running jobs.